# Post XML to API: Need to send CF7 form filed data to API in xml format

Tags: wordpress, xmlhttprequest, wordpress-rest-api, php-curl

I want to send contact form 7 field filled data to an api using post method. Can anyone please help me complete this task?

I have put below code in custom page template and it is generating correct response code but data is not getting received on API.

```
//show contact form 7
echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id=""]' );

//collect fields value
$FirstName =  $_POST['FirstName'];
$LastName =  $_POST['LastName'];
$Email =  $_POST['Email'];

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://post.example.com/LPost',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'<ldlead>
 <FirstName>'.$FirstName.'</FirstName>
 <LastName>'.$LastName.'</LastName>
 <Email>'.$Email.'</Email>
</ldlead> ',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'accept:  application/json',
    'accept-encoding:  gzip, deflate',
    'accept-language:  en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'content-type:  application/xml',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Recevived data sample: Data should be received in this format

```
<ldlead>
 <FirstName>First Name</FirstName>
 <LastName>LastName</LastName>
 <Email>Email id</Email>
</ldlead>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question appears to be missing anything relating to using contact form 7 other than inserting the shortcode. Also in WordPress, you should use `wp_remote_post` instead of `cURL`. While people here can help you if you had something usable that just didn't work, this is just an idea without any real substance. If you spent a little more time trying something, then posted this I'd happily help you, but as it stands, you're just asking for someone to do this for you. SO is not a code writing service, but rather a Q&A site.

Comment: You should start by looking at `wpcf7_before_send_mail` hook, and use that to get your data and then use `wp_remote_post` to push to your API - and include all of that in your function using the `wpcf7_before_send_mail` hook.

Comment: Thanks @HowardE,
I'm working on it as you suggested.

Comment: I have created custom function using wpcf7_before_send_mail hook and curl. if i submit the form, data sent to API and getting correct response code but still there is a problem when i submit the form then cf7 form is not submitting and the loader icon keeps showing on submit.
```if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $resp;
}```
If I remove the  code which is used to show the response then the form is also getting submitted and the data is going to the API but I want the response code so that I can get the confirmation after each submission.